# Center Icons in NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have the following menu with items that show the icon on the left side.

I know that it is a OS X default to have so much white on the left side, but I want to have the icons centered in the middle between the text and the edge.

Is there a way to center these icons ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That space on the left is for the state of the menu item, represented by markers such as check marks and dashes. Short of subclassing NSMenuItem, you're not going to be able to remove that space.

You still have the option to set your own view for each of the menu items. In it, you can position the image and the text the way you want them.

See Apple's [documentation for NSMenuItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Their documentation [Introduction to Application Menus and Pop-up Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/MenuList.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000032i) is informative as well.

Comment: Isn't it possible instead to put a "padding" (the width of the left) on the right edge of the icon to nudge the text a bit further on the right ? Though I have no idea how to make such a padding ..

Comment: @CSS-code Yes. You could either prefix each string with spaces (though that could present problems further down the line, having to take into account those spaces, if you're paying attention to the menu title content), or you could create your own view for each menu item to use, providing the alignment you desire.

Comment: Yeah.. manipulating the strings is not such a good idea (also for translating). It would be better if there was a spacing on the side of the image, instead of changing the string. I don't know so much about xcode, but maybe there exist some property in IB or so to give an item a "padding" or something on the right side ?

Comment: @CSS-code Unfortunately, there aren't any easy answers here. Creating your own menu item view appears to be the best way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I checked your link about custom views. But they don't support key input, which is a really convient way to navigate items .. :(

Comment: @CSS-code Not so. "Keyboard equivalents and type-select continue to use the key equivalent and title as normal." Straight from the docs.

Comment: A view in a menu item can receive all mouse events as normal, but keyboard events are not supported.  - views in menuitems